# Surface fitting

Tags: matlab, surfaces

I do not need a complete answer but just some advice.

I have a sparse matrix of points in a volume. I know a surface passing by these points exists and this surface is mostly flat and relatively smooth with some small harmonic contents. See image below (this surface is a bit too complicated).

I am looking for a method (Laplacian surfaces / Splines / etc.) to fit my points to the best surface of minimal order. Actually I am expecting do describe my surface with less than 30 coefficients.

Any advice of the method I can use (with Matlab or Mathematica) ? If I can get a working example it would be awesome.

[image]

Comment: I think you should post your question in http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BTW, nice pic! :-)

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/14117/4274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist several solutions in Matlab, as follows, they will give you both example programs and references to the underlying methods: [Interpolate scattered data - MATLAB griddata](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html), [Surface Fitting using gridfit - File Exchange - MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit), [Scattered data interpolation - MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html).

The branch of mathematics is called the approximation theory. The general method for smooth scattered data interpolation uses radial basis functions, in Matlab see for example [Scattered Data Interpolation and Approximation using Radial Base Functions.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10056-scattered-data-interpolation-and-approximation-using-radial-base-functions)